# Gremlin query to get the edge between two vertices

Tags: gremlin

Trying something like this

```
List<Edge> result = g.traversal().V().hasLabel("contextlabel").where(__.otherV().hasLabel(labelName)).bothE().toList();
```

But getting below error 
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientVertex cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Edge

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because `V()` returns an `Vertex` and then you try to filter with `where()` which takes that `Vertex` as the incoming item in the stream to evaluate. It tries to call `otherV()` which isn't an available method for a `Vertex`...that method is meant for an edge. I think that you just have the `bothE()` in the wrong place and therefore

```
g.V().hasLabel("contextlabel").
  bothE().
  where(__.otherV().hasLabel(labelName)).
```